# Пояснение строки в Yii2(PHP)

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте.

Вот тупой вопрос,на который я не могу ответить и понять что делает эта строка.

```
$this->buttons[$name] = function ($url) use ($name, $title, $icon) {
 ...
 };
```

Как я понял, берется массив кнопок, с заданным именем. После чего вызывает анонимную функцию, которая принимает урл  (Так ли все понимаю???), после чего наследует имя,заголовок и иконку?

Comment: К массиву кнопок, по ключу `$name` присваивается анонимная функция в качестве значения, принимающая аргументом `$url` и дающая доступ к внешним переменным `$name`, `$title`, `$icon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К массиву кнопок, по ключу `$name` присваивается анонимная функция в качестве значения, принимающая аргументом `$url` и дающая доступ к внешним переменным `$name`, `$title`, `$icon`.

Answer (score 0):

Откуда вы это вытянули? Если из ActionColumn, то это анонимная функция, которая дает возможность переопределить вывод тега `<a>` для кнопки в гриде.

Comment: От части от туда. Расширение картика для грида. Код прикрепил выше.

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected function setDefaultButton($name, $title, $icon)
  {
    if (isset($this->buttons[$name])) {
        return;
    }
    $this->buttons[$name] = function ($url) use ($name, $title, $icon) {
        $opts = "{$name}Options";
        $options = ['title' => $title, 'aria-label' => $title, 'data-pjax' => '0'];
        if ($name === 'delete') {
            $item = isset($this->grid->itemLabelSingle) ? $this->grid->itemLabelSingle : Yii::t('kvgrid', 'item');
            $msg = Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Are you sure to delete this {item}?', ['item' => $item]);
            $options['data-method'] = 'post';
            $options['data-confirm'] = ArrayHelper::remove($options, 'message', $msg);
        }
        $options = array_replace_recursive($options, $this->buttonOptions, $this->$opts);
        $label = $this->renderLabel($options, $title, ['class' => "glyphicon 
        glyphicon-{$icon}"]);
        $link = Html::a($label, $url, $options);
        if ($this->_isDropdown) {
            $options['tabindex'] = '-1';
            return "<li>{$link}</li>\n";
        } else {
            return $link;
        }
    };
  }
```